# How to select data inside excel sheet insert into the mysql database using sql query?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, mysql-workbench

I have above 50,000 rows of data in my excel sheet. It makes too much of time to insert the data into database table because it runs in for loop(spring boot for backend). Can some one suggest me the best for way for insert the data into database from excel in sql query.

Comment: you're using spring data JPA or spring JDBC?

Comment: we are using JPA

Comment: First read data from excel and added to POJO List and use repository.saveAll()

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Can i get some regards as you mentioned. Because i am new to this language

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply with NodeJs Script.

Please find Excel to MySQL in this MySQl library.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-to-mysql

if you don't know how to setup NodeJs environment.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_first_application.htm

Comment: Thanks for effort. Actually we have using java spring boot as backend. So it is not possible in using node js.

Comment: But we did 1 million rows within 10 minutes using nodejs app (ram 512, 1 cpu)

Answer (score 0):

You can achive using bulk insert

***Eg. Excel have columns like***

Empolyee `Name, Email, Username, Address`

You need to create POJO class like below

```
public class Employee {
      String Name;
      String Email;
      String Username;
      String Address;
}
```

Get the records to POJO then use Spring saveAll method to store all records.

```
ArrayList<Employee> excelData = getRecordsfromExcel();
employeeResposity.saveAll(excelData);
```

All records are saved in database.

**Note:**
This is applicable for all inserts not for updates you need to handle different way